# Reading and interpreting data from serial in C++

Tags: python, c++, hex

I'm writing a C++ application that needs read data from serial port (sent by integrated Arduino Leonardo on board), interpret and save it. I have 2 subsequent messages incoming on the serial port: one from a GPS device (via serial pass-through), and another made by data of some sensors.

I can read the data already, but I'm having trouble interpreting it. The data from the GPS is binary packed in SBP protocol. [Protocol structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc2Ma.png)

I can easily read and save it using Python struct, like this:

```
if ser.read().hex() == "55":
  if ser.read(2).hex() == "0102":
     ser.read(7)  # unnecessary information
     lat = struct.unpack('d', ser.read(8))[0]
     lon = struct.unpack('d', ser.read(8))[0]
     alt = struct.unpack('d', ser.read(8))[0]
     ser.read(4)  # unnecessary information                                         
     n_sats = struct.unpack('B', ser.read(1))[0]
     flag = (struct.unpack('B', ser.read(1))[0]) % 4
```

However I'm struggling to make this in C++ (and I need it to be made in C++). I'm reading the data to a buffer like this

```
#include "Serial.h"
#include "SerialReader.h"
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _WIN32
const char *port = "COM3";
#else
const char *port = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
#endif

using namespace std;

const uint16_t sizeBuf = 512;   
    
int main()
{   
    CSerial serial;  //Serial object 
    
    uint8_t *buf = new uint8_t[sizeBuf];

    //Tries to open connection to COM port
    while (tryCont < 10) {
        if (serial.Open(port, 38400)) {
            cout << "Port opened successfully" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Failed to open port! Trying again..." << endl;
            tryCont++;
            Sleep(5000);
        }

        if (tryCont >= 10) {
            cout << "Impossible to open port" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    while (true) {                  

        serial.ReadData(buf, sizeBuf); //Reads data from serial and stores in buffer
   }
}
```

When reading this I would expect to have one byte at each position of the array and them compare and work with them as in the Python code, but that is not the case. The first byte of the message is hex 0x55, but what I have in my buffer is e.g  buf(0) = 0x05 and buf(1) = 0x05.
I tried many ways but I was not able to make this more readable. Aside from this issue, I also need to read information from the value of multiple bytes, and I'm having problems with this as well. I'm really a noob, so sorry if is something obvious.

Below is an exemple of the data read if I print the buffer (I put a space between each member of the array to show what I was talking about). I would expect to have 55, then 01, etc. Not 5, 5, 0, 1.

```
5 5 0 1 E D 9 B F B 6 4 0 6 A A F 0 0 0 0 5 5 6 A 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 1 5 5 D 7 5 5 5 5 5 5 B D 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 5 5 F F 5 5 E D 5 5 0 5 5 E 5 5 5 1 8 5 5 7 0 5 5 0 5 5 F D 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 9 0 3 C 4 E 5 5 5 2 E D 9 1 6 8 5 9 B 2 0 2 4 F 3 F F F F A 1 F 6 F F F F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 0 8 8 6 C 5 5 4 2 E D 9 1 4 8 5 9 B 2 0 E D F 3 F F F F 6 7 F E F F F F C 3 F 5 F F F F 0 0 9 0 1 8 6 D 5 5 2 2 E D 9 1 4 8 5 9 B 2 0 E 2 3 E F F F F F 3 1 D 1 0 1 B B 7 0 0 0 0 9 1 2 C 7 F 5 5 3 2 E D 9 1 6 8 5 9 B 2 0 3 E 6 0 0 4 6 C 4 F E F F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 1 F 1 2 5 5 1 2 E D 9 2 2 8 5 9 B 2 0 7 D 1 6 3 B 7 6 1 9 B 7 4 2 4 0 2 8 A E C 7 3 E 2 3 8 B 5 E C 0 9 D 2 0 C F 8 6 4 1 8 C 5 1 4 0 0 0 0 0 9 1 C F C 9 5 5 0 2 E D 9 2 0 8 5 9 B 2 0 3 B 6 A 1 A 4 5 2 0 9 A 4 4 C 1 7 8 D 8 6 8 4 C C C 5 F 5 0 C 1 B 6 8 6 9 1 9 B 3 C 6 A 4 D 4 1 0 0 9 1 A E 8 A
```

I'm using this [library](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/serialcommunications/article.php/c2503/CSerial--A-C-Class-for-Serial-Communications.htm) to do the serial connection part.

Comment: please show a [mre]. I'd imagine checking the result of `ReadData` would be a good place to start

Comment: Are you sure about your example? `ser.read().hex() == "55"` doesn't mean you get "55", it means you get 1 byte with a value `\x55`.

Comment: Well, the python code works. Maybe I did not express myself very well. A byte with the value 0x55 is exactly what I want to find .

Comment: How are you checking the values in `buf`? Have you checked the result of `ReadData`?

Comment: I'm comparing (e.g. `if (buf[i] == '5' && buf[i + 1] == '5')`) and printing with cout for now. The goal is to do the checks and then write the converted decimal values to a file. `ReadData` returns the number of bytes read. The result varies, something about 170-500 bytes read.